# Write to stdout using character array (not null terminated) c/c++

Tags: c++, stdout

What's the most straightforward way to write to stdout using a character array?  I want to output a slice of a much larger array, and the slice is not null-terminated.  I want to avoid copying the slice to a "proper" null-terminated c-string.

Comment: `std::copy` is appropriate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a pretty obvious solution I didn't find at first. `std::cout` is an instance of `ostream`.

```
void WriteChunk(char *buffer, size_t startpos, size_t length) {
    std::cout.write(buffer + startpos, length);
}
```

so `std::cout.write` does the trick.

Comment: You *could* do it that way ... or you could just use `std::copy`:  `std::copy(buffer, buffer + however_many_characters_you_want, std::ostream_iterator<char><std::cout, ""));`

Comment: how is that simpler than `std::cout.write(buffer + startpos, length)`?

Comment: Note that `write` is an **unformatted** output function; it's very unusual to use unformatted output functions with `std::cout`. That's why @ZacHowland's example is almost certainly better.

Comment: "just" because 1) you are not writing your own function to reinvent the wheel, and 2) it is a very simple function call.

Comment: @ZacHowland the function is not needed, all he does is `std::cout.write(buffer + startpos, length);`.

Comment: @AdamS:  Which still leaves #2.  And (I could be wrong, I'm going off memory here) I don't think `write` flushes the buffer, so if you call `write` it won't write to the console until something else causes the buffer to flush.

Comment: @ZacHowland a C programmer trembles at your suggestion to willy-nilly copy arbitrarily-sized buffers when there is no need

Comment: @Assimilater You misunderstand.  std::copy is an algorithm.  In this case, it is being used to insert items into the standard output buffer.  There is no "willy-nilly" copying going on.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) seems to exactly do what you want :

```
#include <iostream>    // for std::cout
#include <algorithm>   // for std::copy
#include <iterator>    // for std::ostream_iterator

//...
char arr[] = "abcdefij";

std::copy(arr + 2, arr + 5, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
```

This example will write on the standard output: `cde`.

[**Here**](http://ideone.com/UD2ZNI) is a live example.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the bounds of the character array then you could write:

```
char* arr = new char[N];
for(size_t i = min_indx; i < max_indx; ++i) {
  cout << arr[i];
}
```

You just have to make sure min_indx is between 0 and N-1 and max_indx is between 0 and N.

Since we all like library functions to do things, here is the way to do it using `std::copy`:

```
copy(arr + min_indx, arr + max_indx, ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the "department for silly ideas":

```
 class partial_print_wrapper
 {
   private:
     const char *str;
     int start;
     int end;
   public:
     partial_print_wrapper(const char *s, int st, int en) : str(s), start(st), end(en) {}
     friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const partial_print_wrapper& pw);
 };

 ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const partial_print_wrapper& pw)
 {
     for(int i = pw.start; i < pw.end; i++)
     {
         os << pw.str[i];
     }
     return os;
 }

 char *s = "Something quite long";

 cout << print_string_wrapper(s, 3, 8) << endl;
```

Comment: This won't actually compile.

Comment: No, it's missing a semicolon ;)

Comment: And `operator<<` needs to be a non-member because `ostream&` needs to be the first parameter.

Comment: @Simple: Ok, so edited. Of course, like I said, it's a rather silly idea.

Answer (score 1):

[`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) should work.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char a[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    std::ostream out(std::cout.rdbuf());
    out.write(a, 2);
}
```

**Edit**

Creating a separate ostream object is not required, as `std::cout` is a ostream object itself. So `std::cout.write` is sufficient.